# Is it possible to access rails database through iOS app?

Tags: javascript, ios, mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to create a database with rails and then access it through the web application as well as an iOS application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is, why wouldn't it be?

I guess the question is why would you want to?

Any kid capable of watching a YouTube video could sniff out your credentials (whether they're behind SSL or not) and do some funky stuff in/to your database.

Comment: I want to make like an admin panel like page with user login information and then access and edit that same information through an iPhone application. I've researched some ways. I read about making ruby Api. I just wondered if anyone had some specific information I should look into. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: An API would be the most wise thing. For ruby APIs I've always found myself turning to the Grape gem and using ActiveModelSerializers, with Devise for authentication. :)